# Update Row in Excel doesn't find any tables

Tags: excel, power-automate

I want to insert an Excel row when I receive an email from a specific email address.

When I choose the correct Excel file from SharePoint, I get the message "No items" when I want to choose an Excel table.

I have create the table on the Excel sheet and I can see it

What could be wrong? I have no idea.

When I try to manually add the table am getting the below error Error executing the API

> '/codeless/v1.0/drives/b!kZNdFOO93U-MbtstmY9nuhVsOlp8zIJLuRg8xLuPyCB1kDHd42sIRZG18RGskeWZ/items/01AIGG7ZJKA4Y5VQEJWJFYF72E2OFVSAEG/workbook/tables/table1/metadata'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it sharing my excel file in Microsoft teams group.... I think this is a permission related problem. I had excactly the same error,